# Function plot from points result of other function combinations

Tags: matlab, math, wolfram-mathematica, maxima, wxmathplot

I have 2 functions declared in wxmaxima: `f1(x, y)` and `f2(x, y)`. Both contain if-then-else statements and basic arithmetic operations: addition, subtraction, multiplication and division.
For example (just an example, real functions look much more complicated):

```
f1(x, y) := block([],
    if x * y < 123 then x + y
    else if x / y > 7 then x - y
);
```

In both functions `x` and `y` change from 0.1 to 500000.
I need a 3D plot (graph) of the following points:

```
(x, y, z), where f1(x, y) == f2(z, x)
```

Note that it's impossible to extract `z` out from the equation above (and get a new shiny function `f3(x, y)`), since `f1` and `f2` are too complex.

Is this something possible to achieve using any computational software?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
What I need is the plot for

```
F(x, y, z) = 0
```

where

```
F(x, y, z) = f1(x, y) - f2(z, x)
```

Comment: Have you tried just generating the values and placing them in a list `{{x1,y1,z1},...,{xn,yn,zn}}`  then using the function [`ListPlot3D[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot3D.html) ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot generate values. The only thing I know is that `x` and `y` change from 0.1 to 500000. I know nothing about `z`.

Comment: So is f1(x,y) giving values of z?  Furthermore, is f2(z,x) giving values of y?  If this is the case, wouldn't you have 0 or more crossings on the z = y line extending -inf < x < inf.

Comment: Is it fair to assume you could evaluate the function `f2(f1(x,y),x) == f1(x,y)`?  So essentially `z = f1(x,y); return f2(z,x) == z`.  I think you really need to post the equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Maxima, try `implicit_plot(f1(x, y) = f2(x, y), [x, <x0>, <x1>], [y, <y0>, <y1>])` where `<x0>, <x1>, <y0>, <y1>` are some floating point numbers which are the range of the plot. Note that `load(implicit_plot)` is needed since `implicit_plot` is not loaded by default.

As an aside, I see that your function `f1` has the form `if <condition1> then ... else if <condition2> then ...` and that's all. That means if both `<condition1>` and `<condition2>` are false, then the function will return false, not a number. Either you must ensure that the conditions are exhaustive, or put `else ...` at the end of the `if` so that it will return a number no matter what the input.

Answer (score 0):

```
 set = Table[{i,j,0},{i,1,10},{j,0,10}];
```

Gives a list of desired x and y values and use those with a replace all `/.`

```
 set =  set /.{a_ ,b_ ,c_} -> {a,b, f1[a,b] - f2[a,b]} (*Simplified of course*)
```

Set is a 2d list of lists so it needs to be flattened by 1 dimension.

```
 set = Flatten[set,1];

 ListPlot3D[set (*add plot options*)]
```